# Getting information about child process in C

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

I am writing a program in C on a linux machine and I need to get information about a child process. I am trying to use `getrusage()`, but can't seem to get any valuable information. Is there any way I can get the usage statistics (and any other information) of a child process from the parent process given the child's process id?

Answer (score 1):

Note that the POSIX definition of [`getrusage()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getrusage.html) clearly indicates that you can only get the information for child processes that have terminated, not for still running child processes.  There's also a caveat that you have to be paying attention to dying children; if you're ignoring the SIGCHLD signal, you won't get data from `getrusage()` for them.

If you need information about still-running processes, you'll need to grovel around the `/proc` file system for the information for the relevant children; there probably isn't another way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [IPC](http://linux.die.net/man/5/ipc) to communicate between your processes. Otherwise if you only need the information after the child terminated, you can use the `waitpid()` call.